# geocoder connection reset by peer

Tags: python, google-geocoder, geopy

I tried to execute this code:

```
from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3
point = '51.523910, -0.158578'
geolocator = GoogleV3()
address = geolocator.reverse(point)
```

I get this error:

```
error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

I am executing this inside a vagrant machine but when I execute this on my local machine it works !!!

Comment: I see. Are you able to connect to the internet from your vagrant machine? It seems like there is not connection available.

Comment: Yes, I can connect and ping google.com. also if I try curl with the url of the api it works.

Comment: you need to configure your vm network. Check if you port 80 are open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a recent issue of VirtualBox(which is the most probable provider of your vagrant) setting incorrect checksums when networking is set to work as NAT.
Possible decisions are:

- use bridge networking instead of NAT
- update your VirtualBox to a recent [test build](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Testbuilds) (5.1.9 helped in my case)

You can read more at VirtalBox issues on their tracker [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/16126) and [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/16084)

Comment: You save my life. Thank you. updating VirtualBox to 5.1.9 was awesome !!